# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have fragment in that I am using recyclerView but when I running application I am getting error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference"

public class IncomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;
private View v;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_expense, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    assert user != null;
    String uid = user.getUid();
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IncomeDatabase").child(uid);
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Data> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Data>()
            .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<Data>() {
                @NonNull
                @NotNull
                @Override
                public Data parseSnapshot(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    return new Data(Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("amount").getValue().toString())
                            , snapshot.child("type").getValue().toString()
                            , snapshot.child("note").getValue().toString()
                            , snapshot.child("id").getValue().toString(),
                            snapshot.child("date").getValue().toString());
                }
            }).build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data, ViewHolder>(options) {
        @NonNull
        @NotNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.income_recycler_data, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull @NotNull Data model) {
            holder.setAmount(String.valueOf(model.getAmount()));
            holder.setDate(model.getDate());
            holder.setNote(model.getNote());
            holder.setType(model.getType());

        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can't find recycler view by id in the xml layout. Are you sure that you have RecyclerView with id=recycler inside your xml layout(R.layout.fragment_expense - is it right layout id?)?

Maybe you just use a not respective layout. I mean R.layout.fragment_**expense** for **Income**Fragment.

Comment: Check this line:
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_expense, container, false);

Is it right layout for Income fragment?